# What would cause my ASP.Net app to stop function after linking jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to edit my site to work with jQuery Mobile. Whenever I link jQuery mobile, the login button stops working as well as other parts of my web app that rely on javascript.

I use this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
```

I remove it, everything works, I put it back, everything stops working. Yes, I was linking it AFTER my jQuery reference.

I asked it in a simplistic way because I'm assuming there is an easy answer I'm overlooking.

**EDIT:**

It is able to see if the username and password is incorrect or not, but unable to transition me to the defaultURL following the login page.

Comment: can you provide the message of your console ?

Comment: Well in order to test it on a mobile device I've been publishing my changes to my site and refreshing my device. So, I don't have any errors to show. Other than that by linking the mobile library, login stops working. What other info can I provide to give insight here?

Comment: I can change ANYTHING else, but if I link jquery mobile in either the shared layout page or the login coded page, it stops working.

Comment: The issue is apparently with Ajax. Ajax must be disabled.